# GeoFinder Latitude Error

Tags: add-on, module

I'm trying to setup GeoFinder and I keep getting this error:

> Latitude field not found, please make sure you have it entered
>   correctly in the latitude parameter.

I thought it would be my segments, but my url is `/site/results2/10030/1/`

and the code from the results page is:

```
    {exp:geofinder:location_results channel="personal_trainer_directory" status="open" limit="10" geoquery="{segment_3}" radius="{segment_4}" latitude="{latitude}" longitude="{longitude}" distance_mode="miles" disable="
"}

{if count == 1}
<p>You searched for personal trainers within <strong>{radius}</strong> {distance_mode} of <strong>{geoquery}</strong>, <strong>{total_results}</strong> personal trainers were found.</p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
{/if}

<tr><td><strong>{title}</strong><br/>{trainer_address}<br/>{trainer_city}, {trainer_state} {trainer_zip}</td><td><a href="{trainer_url}" title="{trainer_url}">{trainer_url}</a></td><td class="distance"><strong>{distance}</strong> {distance_mode}</td></tr>
{if count == total_results}
</table>
{/if}
{if no_results}
<p>We found no personal trainers based on your search.</p>
{/if}
{/exp:geofinder:location_results}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure, but I think the longitude and latitude parameters are looking for the field name, and not the field value. Try removing the curly brackets around those two fields and see if it works.

Comment: tried removing curly brackets, emptying the fields, and tried manually adding the latitude and longitude that i got from this site: http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html .. still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Actually removing the curly brackets helped me:

```
{exp:geofinder:member_results 
  member_group="members" 
  limit="5"  
  geoquery="{segment_3}" 
  radius="{segment_4}"  
  latitude="member_latitude" 
  longitude="member_longitude" 
  distance_mode="miles" 
}
```